# Passive voice misuse?

Tags: passive-voice

> "I was defeated by one of my biggest enemies."

When I checked the above sentence for grammar issues using Grammarly, it pointed out that I misused the passive voice. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out the reason for this, since I'm using the free version. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this sentence, please?

Comment: Your sentence is flawless. It's perfect in every way. Don't pay any money for Grammarly!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Grammar checkers are never 100% perfect.